# RuntimeWarning with a code for stepper motor

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, runtime-error, raspberry-pi3

In order to make our motor run, we are trying this code but apparently it has many errors. Can someone help us?

```
RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

pinDir = 24
pinStep = 26
numSteps = 200
microPausa = 0.005


GPIO.setup(pinDir,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(pinStep,GPIO.OUT)

while True:

        GPIO.output(pinDir,0)

        for i in range(0,numSteps):
                GPIO.output(pinStep, True)
                time.sleep(microPausa)
                GPIO.output(pinStep, False)
                time.sleep(microPausa)

        time.sleep(microPausa)

        GPIO.output(pinDir, 1)

        for i in range(0,numSteps):
                GPIO.output(pinStep, True)
                time.sleep(microPausa)
                GPIO.output(pinStep, False)
                time.sleep(microPausa)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

> carlini.py:12: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
>     GPIO.setup(pinDir,GPIO.OUT)
>   carlini.py:13: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
>     GPIO.setup(pinStep,GPIO.OUT)

Answer (score 3):

A `RuntimeWarning` is just a *warning* not an *error*. It will carry on while giving you a warning. If you read it, it actually tells you what the warning is for, and how to prevent it:

> This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.
>
> Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.

This means the GPIO pin you're using has been set up before, and not cleaned up. This is not really a problem for you as you're just re-running your code. You can disable warnings by adding `Use GPIO.setwarnings(False)` to the top of your file (after `GPIO.setmode`).

Answer (score 0):

Did you run it multiple times and stopped it via a keyboard interrupt (like ctrl+c)?
If so, the GPIOs are still set.

You may want to use a try/except/finally block, to properly unset the GPIOs:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

pinDir = 24
pinStep = 26
numSteps = 200
microPausa = 0.005


GPIO.setup(pinDir,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(pinStep,GPIO.OUT)
try:
    while True:

        GPIO.output(pinDir,0)

        for i in range(0,numSteps):
                GPIO.output(pinStep, True)
                time.sleep(microPausa)
                GPIO.output(pinStep, False)
                time.sleep(microPausa)

        time.sleep(microPausa)

        GPIO.output(pinDir, 1)

        for i in range(0,numSteps):
                GPIO.output(pinStep, True)
                time.sleep(microPausa)
                GPIO.output(pinStep, False)
                time.sleep(microPausa)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass # or print("received a keyboard interrupt, exiting.")
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Mind that the first time you run this script, you will get the same warning (as it comes from previous executions), unless you run the python script

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.cleanup()
```